# Problem with password provided in mysql console

Tags: mysql, lamp, ubuntu-20.04

I installed lamp like [here](https://devanswers.co/install-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-20-04/). During I configure mysql security (mysql_secure_installation) I wrote my password but after I want to login to mysql console I have an error "Access danied". Password is ok. I wrote that in gedit and pass to the terminal. Why I can't login to mysql console? In Virtual Box I tryed do this same and write simple password. Problem is this same.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `PHP` ?

Comment: What is your exact error message? Probably you pass wrong password. Repeat step with mysql configuration and be careful with typing password this time.

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. I wrote this same password which I check in installation process. I install on VB too with other password, I tryed install again (mysql_secure_installation) with other password and any time I have this same.

Comment: What command are you using to log in to MySQL on the command line?